# How to route all traffic from VPN client through LAN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nat

I have a VPN server (ubuntu) with 2 interface:

```
eth0: A.B.C.D
eth1: 192.168.8.45
```

I've setup VPN which create tun interface. VPN IP is 10.8.0.0/24 Now from VPN client (10.8.0.6) I can connect to my LAN (192.168.8.0/24), ping and access server on LAN. I've forced all traffic through LAN by setting in server.conf

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

And set IP tables

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

With these setting, I can connect to the internet, but using IP address of eth0 (A.B.C.D), not through eth1 as I want.

If I try to set:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then I cannot connect to the internet.

So what is the problem? I've already googled but no answer in this case.
Could you help me? I will really appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you try to set `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE` you route add traffic from VPN to eth1. But I think you doesn't have route to 0.0.0.0/0 trough eth1. 
There not enough information about your network, but you could add iptables rule `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.8.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` and try to check what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route on your VPN server:

```
ip route add 192.168.8.0/24 via 192.168.8.45 dev eth1
```

This will tell your system to send everything target to 192.168.8 via eth1.
Also, it's a good idea making this route persistent.